# Git: why the \; doesn't work in the config-file for me?

Tags: git

Git for Windows.
I am learning Git.
The quote of `git help config`:

> A line that defines a value can be continued to the next line by
>   ending it with a \; the backquote and the end-of-line are stripped.

I tried this:

```
[user]
    name = Andrey\;
  Bushman
```

and this:

```
[user]
    name = 'Andrey\;
  Bushman'
```

and this:

```
[user]
    name = 'Andrey '\;
  'Bushman'
```

and this:

```
[user]
    name = 'Andrey \;'
  'Bushman'
```

instead of this (working variant):

```
[user]
    name = Andrey Bushman
```

but I get an error: `fatal: error in 6 line.` (this is index of the line with `\;`) for command:

```
git config --global user.name
```

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's probably because the ";" is a punctuation character in that sentence. It's not part of the character sequence to use to continue to the next line, i.e. you should only use "\".